# How to set a dynamic zoom on google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like, when I open the map on my website, start from an higher level and zoom to a lower level.

For example :

```js
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoom: 15,
    center: location,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'myScale']
    }
};
```

zoom must start to 15 and go to 10 automatically.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?

```js
var curZoom = 15;
var zoomInterval;

// create map with zoom level curZoom
// ...

zoomInterval = setInterval(function () {
    curZoom -= 1;
    map.setZoom(curZoom);
    if (curZoom === 10) {
        clearInterval(zoomInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hehehe, yeah this is a overkill solution :) In fact the map is loaded every time I do a zoom. And the effect is a bit horrible :) Would be nice use some API that load at the beginning the whole level, and zoom automatically. I think there's somethings...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's the only solution that I can think of... Good luck! :)